# Does the default route calculator use shortest time or shortest distance?

Tags: routes, here-api, here-maps-rest

When HERE is calculating a route, by default, does it use shortest distance or shortest time?  We have an integration for our routing software to use HAZMAT routes, but we do not specific how to calculate the route other than which roads to exclude due to the chemical they are hauling.  Our customer is asking if it uses the shortest distance or shortest time to calculate the route after that?

Answer (score 1):

In [Routing API v7](https://developer.here.com/documentation/routing/dev_guide/topics/resource-calculate-route.html) (in maintenance) the mode is mandatory, so you need to specify it (fastest, shortest or balanced).

In [Routing API V8](https://developer.here.com/documentation/routing-api/8.20.3/api-reference-swagger.html) it's not mandatory and the default is `fast`

Comment: Yep, it is written explicitly in the documentation that the default is `fast` as Tomas said.